# Is there a way to create an arbitrary dimension matrix that looks like a matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix

I am trying to use Gram polynomials of optimal order to fit a data set **y**.  That is, fit a linear model y=mat.**a** where mat is a matrix of Gram polynomials evaluated over the domain of y (see pg 702-3 of Random Phenomena: Fundamentals of Probability and Statistics for Engineers B.A. Ogunnaike CRC Press (2010)).

The simplest way I have found to create the Gram polynomials using recursion is

```
p[m_, x_, n_] := If[m == 0, 1, If[m == 1, x, 
x p[m - 1, x, n] - (m - 1)^2 (n^2 - (m - 1)^2)/((4 (m - 1)^2 - 1) (n - 1)^2) p[m - 2, 
   x, n]]];
```

which can be put into a tabular form

```
matt = Table[p[m, x, n], {m, 0, 3, 1}, {x, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}]]

mat=Transpose[matt]
```

and then use for the usual least squares estimation of the polynomial coefficients **a**

```
a=Inverse[matt.mat].matt.y
```

That works, but for higher order polynomials, the array output is too cumbersome and MatrixForm turns a functional array into a useless display object.

The Basic Math palette can create a matrix that looks like a matrix (CNTRL-Enter,CNTRL-, etc.).  Is there a way to create a matrix of arbitrary dimensions that looks like a matrix using a formula?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. A matrix in Mathematica is represented with a List of column vectors (Lists), e.g. ``mat = { {...}, {...}, {...} }``. You can type this out by hand, or generate it with some function, like ``Table``. Whenever a calculation or a function takes a matrix as an input, it should be provided in this form. However, if you want to print it in a usual, rectangular form, you use ``MatrixForm[mat]``.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, i.e., you would like a way to create expressions that look and act like matrices, `MatrixForm` should work.

From Details & Options in the [documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) for `MatrixForm`:

> The typeset form of MatrixForm[expr] is interpreted the same as expr when used in input.

and

> When an input evaluates to MatrixForm[expr], MatrixForm does not appear in the output.

So if `MatrixForm` is the outermost function, your output really is a matrix, not just a displayed form of it.

Now, the problem of `MatrixForm` creating a "useless display object" only happens if the `MatrixForm` is not the outermost function but is part of a subexpression. For example, from the the Possible Issues section of the documentation page,

```
e = MatrixForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

causes the variable `e` to have `MatrixForm` in it. If you want to be able to do mathematical computations with `e`, the solution is to set `e` first and then use `MatrixForm`, like so:

```
MatrixForm[e = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}]
```